# The URI 'http://' is malformed in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri()

Tags: drupal

I have a fresh install Drupal 8.7.6, which I'm using to upgrade a Drupal 7 website. I installed a module that the new website will require, and want to run `upgrade.php`. However, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentException: The URI 'http://' is malformed. in Drupal\Core\Url::fromUri() (line 274 of /opt/drupal8_diff/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Url.php).
```

Is this possibly the result of some configuration error?

Comment: What is the module that you installed? Do you get errors on any other pages? Has the upgrade actually run and generated migrations in the DB? There is not enough information in your question to help you. Also, a full trace of the error would help, it will probably be on the log page.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. The module i installed is "Asset Injector". I haven't run the actual migration process, if that's what you're asking. Also, sorry, but I'm a new user, so I'm not exactly sure where to look for the full trace. Where is it located? I will update the question once I find it.